# Duplicação de evento jQuery

Tags: jquery

#### Cenário teste

**index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function carregar() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'inc.php',
                success:function(response){
                    $('#ret').html(response).show();
                },
                error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log(thrownError);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="carregar()">Carregar</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="ret"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**inc.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 67) {   
            clone();
        }
    });

    function clone() {
        const template = $('#elementos > #el').last();
        const novo = template.clone();
        $('#elementos').append(novo);
    }
</script>
<div>
    <button onclick="clone()">Clonar</button>
    <div id="elementos">
        <p id="el">Elemento</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Simulação

O `index`, tem um botão que chama por *Ajax* o conteúdo de `inc.php`, onde tem uma função que clona o elemento com `id="el"` pelo botão "clonar" ou por atalho de teclas "Alt+C".

O que acontece é que, cada vez que "recarrega" o conteúdo de `inc.php` pelo botão "carregar" do `index`, ele adiciona +1 clone somente pelo atalho, mas não pelo botão, como abaixo:

[image: bug]

---

#### Dúvida

- Por que isso acontece somente com o "atalho" definido?

Comment: **1.** Sempre que o evento `keydown` é utilizado no *jQuery*, ele é adicionado (e não substituído). Ou seja, toda vez que a página `inc.php` for carregada, uma nova ação será adicionada no evento supramencionado. **2.** Isso não ocorre com o botão "clonar", pois a função `onclick` sempre terá apenas um comando e a função será substituída. Não sei se deu para entender (qualquer coisa monto um *gif*).

Comment: Creio que vc inverteu no texto (no título está ok): quem duplica é o atalho e não o botão :D

Comment: @Sam verdade! Valeu!! Kkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque cada vez que você carrega, é criado um novo *event listener* `$(document).keydown` na memória, e vai acumulando. No caso do botão isso não ocorre porque ele chama uma função que não duplica no carregamento.

O que você tem que fazer é impedir que o `$(document).keydown` seja executado a cada carregamento, ou seja, que ele entre apenas 1 vez na memória.

Uma sugestão é criar uma variável (chamei de `flag`) inicialmente *false* e colocar o `$(document).keydown` dentro de um `if` e alterar o valor da variável para `true`. Assim, o trecho dentro do `if` só será executado na primeira vez, evitando duplicar o `$(document).keydown`:

```
var flag;

if(!flag){      
   flag = true;
   $(document).keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 67) {   
         clone();
      }
   });
}

function clone() {
   const template = $('#elementos > #el').last();
   const novo = template.clone();
   $('#elementos').append(novo);
}
```

Comment: Pode testar. Vai funcionar como uma luva. ;?)

Comment: 100%! Valeuuu! ✌️